# CSS Formulario, disposición de elementos

Tags: html, css

Tengo un formulario `HTML` que tiene diversas filas y en cada una de ellas hay diferentes cantidades de 'columnas', tal como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la segunda fila se observan 2 `input` (Rut y Nombre) pero estos se encuentran bastante separados, lo cual deseo cambiar para que quede como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he modificado mi `css` varias veces pero no logro generar el cambio deseado.

Adjunto código `HTML` y `CSS`:

```css
.card-body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.form-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

    .form-container .row {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        gap: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

.form-element {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: calc(20% - 10px);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

    .form-element.textarea {
        flex-basis: calc(60% - 10px);
    }

    .form-element.number-input {
        flex-basis: calc(40% - 10px);
    }

label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input, select, textarea {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*padding: 5px 10px;*/
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    input[type=number] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0;
        -moz-appearance: textfield;
    }

    input[readonly] {
        color: -internal-light-dark(graytext, rgb(170, 170, 170));
        opacity: 0.7;
        cursor: default;
        outline: none;
    }

textarea {
    height: 6em;
    resize: none;
}

.button-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

button {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="card-body">
        <form class="form-container">
            <!-- 1st row: 4 inputs (2 select, 2 text) -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-element">
                    @Html.Hidden("tipoOficio", @ViewData["TOfic"])
                    <label for="TOficio">Tipo de Oficio:</label>
                    <select id="TOficio" name="TOficio" required="">
                        <option selected="selected" value="">Tipo Oficio</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    @Html.Hidden("tipoCobrador", @ViewData["TCob"])
                    <label for="TCob">Tipo Cobrador:</label>
                    <select id="TCob" name="TCob" required="" disabled>
                        <option selected="selected" value="">Tipo Cobrador</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="OficioPrefactura">Oficio Prefactura:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="OficioPrefactura" name="OficioPrefactura" readonly />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="NumRegistro">Número de Registro:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="NumRegistro" name="NumRegistro" value="@ViewData["Registro"]" readonly />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row" id="CodigoGuarnicion">
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="CodUnid">Código Unidad:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="CodUnid" name="CodUnid" value="@ViewData["Guarnicion"]" maxlength="10" required onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="NombreUnidad">Nombre Unidad:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="NombreUnidad" name="NombreUnidad" value="@ViewData["NombreCob"]" readonly />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" id="DNI">
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="Rut">Rut:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="Rut" name="Rut" value="@ViewData["RutCob"]" maxlength="12" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="Nombre">Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" value="@ViewData["NombreCob"]" maxlength="255" readonly />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                @*2nd row: 5 inputs (2 text, 2 select, 1 text)*@
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="NumOficio">Número Oficio:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="NumOficio" name="NumOficio" readonly value="@ViewData["Oficio"]" required onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\/]/g, '')" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="OrdenCompra">Número de OC:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="OrdenCompra" name="OrdenCompra" value="@ViewData["Oficio"]" readonly onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    @Html.Hidden("codigoOc", @ViewData["CodOC"])
                    <label for="OrdenCompra">Código de OC:</label>
                    <select id="Codigo" name="Codigo" disabled>
                        <option value="" selected="">Código</option>
                        @*<option value="OI">OI</option>*@
                        <option value="SE">SE</option>
                        <option value="CM">CM</option>
                        <option value="AG">AG</option>
                        <option value="OI">OI</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    @Html.Hidden("Anno", @ViewData["AñoOC"])
                    <label for="AñoOC">Año de OC:</label>
                    <select id="AñoOC" name="AñoOC" disabled>
                        <option value="" selected="">Año</option>
                        @for (int i = DateTime.Now.Year; i > (DateTime.Now.Year - 8); i--)
                        {
                            <option value="@i">@i</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="Prefactura">Número de Prefactura:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="Prefactura" name="Prefactura" value="@ViewData["Pref"]" readonly onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- 3rd row: 4 date inputs -->
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="FecRecepcion">Fecha Recepción:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="FecRecepcion" name="FecRecepcion" value="@ViewData["FecRecepcion"]" max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" readonly required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="FecDocumento">Fecha Oficio:</label>
                    <input type="date" id="FecDocumento" name="FecDocumento" value="@ViewData["FecOficio"]" max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" readonly required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="FecRegistro">Fecha Registro:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="FecRegistro" name="FecRegistro" value="@ViewData["FecRegistro"]" readonly />
                </div>
                <div class="form-element">
                    <label for="FecDig">Fecha Digitación:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="FecDig" name="FecDig" value="@ViewData["FecDigitacion"]" readonly />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- 4th row: 2 inputs (1 textarea, 1 number) -->
                <div class="form-element full">
                    <label for="Obs">Observación:</label>
                    <textarea id="obs" name="obs" placeholder="Observación" rows="5" cols="50" maxlength="255">@ViewData["Obs"]</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-element full">
                    <label for="Total">Total:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="Total" name="Total" readonly required maxlength="14" value="@ViewData["Total"]" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <!-- 5th row: 2 buttons -->
        <div class="button-container">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success BtnForm" id="Grabar" name="Grabar">Grabar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary BtnForm" id="Volver" name="Volver" onclick="location.href = '/Transac/AdministrarOficios'; trytoredirect();">Volver</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Por más que modifico el `css`, específicamente el `.row` y `.form-element`, no logro cuadrar el `input` nombre de la manera que deseo.

Alguien que se maneje con `css` que me pueda orientar para poder mejorar mi codificación, se lo agradezco de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sería la solución más óptima, pero traté de acercarme más a tu resultado esperado, solamente ajusté un poco los valores de la propiedad `flex-grow` a tus dos `.form-element` de `#CodigoGuarnicion` (que son esos 2 inputs).

---

Con `nth-child(1)` indico a qué `.form-element` quiero ingresar, si es `(1)` ingreso al primero, si es `(2)`, al segundo, sucesivamente:

```
#CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(1) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 10;
}

#CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(2) input {
  width: 59%;
}
```

Y para no perder el orden y desborde de tus `divs` en resoluciones pequeñas, los volví a como estaba antes cuando superemos el ancho de `671px`, utilizando la regla `@media`:

```
@media (max-width: 671px) {
  #CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(1) {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  #CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(2) {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  #CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(2) input {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Te recomendaría usar las [**rejillas de Bootstrap**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/columns/), para tener con facilidad estos resultados.

---

Demo:

```css
.card-body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-container .row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-element {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: calc(20% - 10px);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.form-element.textarea {
  flex-basis: calc(60% - 10px);
}

.form-element.number-input {
  flex-basis: calc(40% - 10px);
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

input, select, textarea {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /*padding: 5px 10px;*/
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=number] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input[readonly] {
  color: -internal-light-dark(graytext, rgb(170, 170, 170));
  opacity: 0.7;
  cursor: default;
  outline: none;
}

textarea {
  height: 6em;
  resize: none;
}

.button-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

button {
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(1) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 10;
}

#CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(2) input {
  width: 59%;
}

@media (max-width: 671px) {
  #CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(1) {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  #CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(2) {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  #CodigoGuarnicion .form-element:nth-child(2) input {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <form class="form-container">
    <!-- 1st row: 4 inputs (2 select, 2 text) -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="TOficio">Tipo de Oficio:</label>
        <select id="TOficio" name="TOficio" required="">
          <option selected="selected" value="">Tipo Oficio</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="TCob">Tipo Cobrador:</label>
        <select id="TCob" name="TCob" required="" disabled>
          <option selected="selected" value="">Tipo Cobrador</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="OficioPrefactura">Oficio Prefactura:</label>
        <input type="text" id="OficioPrefactura" name="OficioPrefactura" readonly />
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="NumRegistro">Número de Registro:</label>
        <input type="text" id="NumRegistro" name="NumRegistro" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row" id="CodigoGuarnicion">
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="CodUnid">Código Unidad:</label>
        <input type="number" id="CodUnid" name="CodUnid" maxlength="10" required onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="NombreUnidad">Nombre Unidad:</label>
        <input type="text" id="NombreUnidad" name="NombreUnidad" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="DNI">
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="Rut">Rut:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Rut" name="Rut" maxlength="12" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="Nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" maxlength="255" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="NumOficio">Número Oficio:</label>
        <input type="text" id="NumOficio" name="NumOficio" readonly required onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\/]/g, '')" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="OrdenCompra">Número de OC:</label>
        <input type="number" id="OrdenCompra" name="OrdenCompra" readonly onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="OrdenCompra">Código de OC:</label>
        <select id="Codigo" name="Codigo" disabled>
          <option value="" selected="">Código</option>
          <option value="OI">OI</option>
          <option value="SE">SE</option>
          <option value="CM">CM</option>
          <option value="AG">AG</option>
          <option value="OI">OI</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="AñoOC">Año de OC:</label>
        <select id="AñoOC" name="AñoOC" disabled>
          <option value="" selected="">Año</option>
          <option value="@i">@i</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="Prefactura">Número de Prefactura:</label>
        <input type="number" id="Prefactura" name="Prefactura" readonly onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- 3rd row: 4 date inputs -->
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="FecRecepcion">Fecha Recepción:</label>
        <input type="date" id="FecRecepcion" name="FecRecepcion" max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" readonly required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="FecDocumento">Fecha Oficio:</label>
        <input type="date" id="FecDocumento" name="FecDocumento" max="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" readonly required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="FecRegistro">Fecha Registro:</label>
        <input type="text" id="FecRegistro" name="FecRegistro" readonly />
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="FecDig">Fecha Digitación:</label>
        <input type="text" id="FecDig" name="FecDig" readonly />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- 4th row: 2 inputs (1 textarea, 1 number) -->
      <div class="form-element full">
        <label for="Obs">Observación:</label>
        <textarea id="obs" name="obs" placeholder="Observación" rows="5" cols="50" maxlength="255"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-element full">
        <label for="Total">Total:</label>
        <input type="number" id="Total" name="Total" readonly required maxlength="14" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <!-- 5th row: 2 buttons -->
  <div class="button-container">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success BtnForm" id="Grabar" name="Grabar">Grabar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary BtnForm" id="Volver" name="Volver" onclick="location.href = '/Transac/AdministrarOficios'; trytoredirect();">Volver</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Puedes ver mejor los resultados [**en este enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/MWPwXbZ).

Comment: Gracias, no entiendo mucho de css pero se llegó a lo que andaba buscando jajaja